# Wordpress My First Plugin - Displays in admin - in frontend displays "Hello World"

Tags: wordpress

I created my first plugin which displays a menu in the WordPress admin

There are 2 problems that I am not able to understand or how to fix it in WordPress.

1. The plugin displays the name `Zach First Plugin` in the admin which is fine, but when I click on it, it displays the actual upload form. How to hide that form from the admin, it should display only in the frontend with the shortcode (wherever I add it). Screenshot added
2. When I add the plugin in any post with this short code `[pdf id=""]` it doesnt display the upload form just displays Hello world, not sure what code changes I should do.

[image]

Here is my code

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Zach First Plugin
Description: Plugin to create a menu in WP
Author: Zach
Version: 0.1
*/
//Call function to create an Admin menu element
add_action('admin_menu', 'test_plugin_setup_menu');

function test_plugin_setup_menu(){
        add_menu_page( 'Zach Plugin Page', 'Zach Plugin', 'manage_options', 'test-plugin', 'test_init' );
}

//This function is called to handle the click function on the Admin menu element
function test_init(){
        test_handle_post();
?>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <h2>Upload a File</h2>
        <!-- Form to handle the upload - The enctype value here is very important -->
        <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type='file' id='test_upload_pdf' name='test_upload_pdf'></input>
                <?php submit_button('Upload') ?>
        </form>
<?php
}

// Handle the file upload
function test_handle_post(){
        // First check if the file appears on the _FILES array
        if(isset($_FILES['test_upload_pdf'])){
                $pdf = $_FILES['test_upload_pdf'];

                // Use the wordpress function to upload
                // test_upload_pdf corresponds to the position in the $_FILES array
                // 0 means the content is not associated with any other posts
                $uploaded=media_handle_upload('test_upload_pdf', 0);
                // Error checking using WP functions
                if(is_wp_error($uploaded)){
                        echo "Error uploading file: " . $uploaded->get_error_message();
                }else{
                        echo "File upload successful!";
                }
        }
}

//Add a Shortcode
add_shortcode("pdf", "test_process_shortcode");

function test_process_shortcode(){
        return "<span style='color:blue;'>Hello world!</span>";
}

?>
```

Comment: "This function is called to handle the click function on the Admin menu element" your init function is what you are seeing on the admin page.

Comment: Why do you want an admin page, if you just want to add a custom shortcode?

Comment: @Stender In the admin I just need to show :Static: description nothing else for now, in future I can add settings may be. but it should hide the form, remove hello world and display the form in any post where I use shortcode. The form upload works great, but not sure how to hide and show